Building muscle at home gym & cardio 4/5 days
I'm looking for a muscle-building program (4-5 days/week) that I can follow at my home gym. I have an elliptical bike, water rower, dumbbells, barbell (straight and EZ curl), and I'd like to incorporate some cardio as well.
I've heard that excessive cardio can hinder muscle growth, so I'd appreciate a program that balances both effectively.
For reference, I'm a 33-year-old male, 171 cm tall, and currently weigh 105 kg. I've been working out for 6 months (cardio and bodybuilding) and have lost 25 kg since October. I feel that I loose fat, but I don’t feel big muscles development. For the nutrition I’m getting around 140grams of protein per day (diverse food + whey protein isolate). I also started taking creatine 4 days ago.
Right now, my routine is a bit random: 45 minutes elliptical, 10 minutes water rower, then 1 hour of bodybuilding following the Jefit beginner dumbbell split routine:

Day 1: Chest, shoulders, triceps
Day 2: Back, biceps, forearms
Day 3: Legs, calves, core

I'd love some guidance on a more structured program that considers my equipment and weight/height stats.
Thanks!

The interference effect is grossly overblown for non-professional athletes. Sure, if you want to absolutely maximize strength or cardio metabolic adaptations, training to also maximize the other will hinder your efforts. But people just training for health and fitness need not worry at all about it. Just train both as hard as you like. You’ll be fine, and probably better for it.
